# Best practices for item selection in Latent Class Cluster Analysis?

Tags: clustering, latent-class

I'm interested in developing a set of clusters pertaining to shopping habits using a dataset from a survey that a colleague recently fielded. The survey contains a wide array of topics--some related to shopping habits, some not. There's a pretty big set of demographic items as well (race, gender, political affiliation, SES, etc.)

What are the best practices for selecting items to include in my LCCA? Should I only use items relevant to shopping habits? Should I throw the whole dataset in? Is it better to include individual items, or should I combine scales of multiple items into single indicators?

Any advice or relevant sources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: While there are protocols that can search for potential clusters, your problem (and solution) here suggests that you need a very strong theoretical framework to justify the variables (and in turn, their validity).  In brief, you need to make a decision about what to include in the model based on theory, not (under-informed) statistical analyses.